# How to make a specific rectangle flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make shape like the one below and write on it in my flutter app
[image]

How can I make it?

Comment: For easy solution you can keep image like that one.

Comment: Does text use background color? like screen cut?

Comment: @GHPrakash do you mean that I pick up an image like this shape and I write on it?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sorry I didn't get it, what do you mean?

Comment: Does the below answers satisfy your question?  Do you like to have transparent color for text so that you can see below image(behind the red) color?

Answer (score 2):

you can use ClipPath

```
 class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.red,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child:const Text("Your Text"),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 50, 25);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(MyCustomClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You should make a `CustomPainter` like this:

```
class MyCustomRectangle extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  const MyCustomRectangle({
    this.color = Colors.red,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = color;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - (size.height / 2), size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => oldDelegate != this;
}
```

then use it like this:

```
CustomPaint(
          painter: MyCustomRectangle(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 36.0,
              vertical: 8.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Free Home Delivery 30 min",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 23.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

the output:
[image]